# Angular-Cli Not working in sub module

Tags: git, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm creating an angular app using the angular cli, and I'm having errors with the ng build and ng serve commands when the project is in a git sub module directory.

I have 2 versions of the project. The first is my original git repository where I do all the dev work for the app. For SEO Reasons, I have an additional jekyll repository to maintain the static content.To make the build process easier, I'm try to include the angular repository in the static content repository as a sub module, as this is where the problems start.

For some reason I can run ng serve/build fine with no problems in the original repo, but when I try to build in the static repo I get various web pack issues, the most recent being "Cannot find module 'webpack-sources'"

I'm unsure why the project is 'working' in one place and not another, sense both locations should have the exact same content. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

I've run npm install in both directories with no errors. Here is the package.json for the project (diff checker tells me both repos are the same)

Original:

```
{
  "name": "inspinia",
  "version": "2.7.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
    "animate.css": "3.1.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.110.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "firebase": "^4.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "jvectormap": "1.2.2",
    "metismenu": "^2.5.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.9.1",
    "peity": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.88",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Jesse, in that submodule folder, did you run npm install before trying to build/serve? If so, then you need to add to your question what else you already tried, so we can assist you better.

Comment: Also, the "both locations should have the exact same content" part, not really, look at your package.json versions as for example, ^2.2.0 is quite different to ~2.2.0 or 2.2.0. My point is, both locations most likely don't have the exact module versions unless you are locking your versions. That also causes the works in one place, not in another, issue, very common with npm.

Comment: Thanks for the input Juan. I have indeed run npm install before trying to build/serve, so the node modules folder is there. I've gone ahead and added the 2 package.json files to my post, although they are exactly the same. Perhaps I should remove one and just state they are the same instead of posting both and taking up more screen space.

Comment: Just one package.json is useful, That already tells me a lot. Let's try this: [npm install webpack-sources] I think the issue is around the extract-text-webpack-plugin that maybe didn't finish successfully. Try that npm install and if you get a new missing module error, remove node_modules there and do a npm install again. If you still get errors after that, update your question with those.